# Boolean в system.typInfo

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Почему в `system.typInfo` нет константы для типа `boolean`? Каким образом можно определить логический тип через эти константы?

Answer (score 0):

За это отвечает константа `tkEnumeration`.